# Add Value to 3 Registry locations

Tags: vb6

I am trying to add a value to 3 locations in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intel\Indeo
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Intel\Indeo
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-669792009-2657969199-152103076-1000\Software\Intel\Indeo
```

This is the string I need to add to each registry path:

`"Options"="360611321911"`

For some reason I am unable to test this code just to see if it adds the value:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite "HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-669792009-2657969199-152103076-1000\Software\Intel\Indeo", "C:\Program Files\FastTuner\Clean.exe"
```

Comment: I don't understand, why are you unable to test it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add these two functions to your project to work with values in the Registry:

```
' Write Reg:
'       Write to the Windows Registry
'       RegType should be 'REG_SZ' for string, 'REG_DWORD' for an integer,
'       'REG_BINARY' for a binary or boolean, and 'REG_EXPAND_SZ' for an expandable string
Function WriteReg(RegPath, Value, RegType)
    Dim Key
    Dim objRegistry
    Set objRegistry = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
    Key = objRegistry.RegWrite(RegPath, Value, RegType)
    WriteReg = Key
End Function

' Read Reg:
'       Read from the Windows Registry
Function ReadReg(RegPath)
    Dim Key
    Dim objRegistry
    Set objRegistry = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
    Key = objRegistry.RegRead(RegPath)
    ReadReg = Key
End Function
```